# There isnt menu folder in android studio project

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, menu

I am newbie with android and android studio.

I am following a book to learn android, I want to create a menu for my activity but in the project structure window, I am unable to find the menu folder and the sample menu files.

I attached a screenshot of my Project Explorer:

[image]

Comment: you can add by right click on res-> new android resource directory
in the resource type choose menu

Comment: @OussemaAroua yes but there isnt the content and i must write it

Comment: Right click on **res** folder, select **new >> Directory**. Name the directory as **menu** and create your menu xml layouts here in this **menu** directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not all folders are created automatically with new projects. If you need it, just press right mouse button while pointers is over `res/` folder in your project and select `New...` -> `Directory` and name it `menu` and then you put  your menu XMLs inside that folder.

Answer (score 7):

Following are steps to create Menu folder in res:

1. Right click on res
2. New --> Android Resource Directory
3. Name your directory and set Resource type as Menu.

**Your Menu is created.**

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on res folder → New → Android Resource Directory:

[image]

Select "Menu" from resource type:

[image]

Click OK:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not Default menu folder created,,,,,,, Create one under --> res/menu

Create your menu xml

See the documentation  [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus)